# Using Vue3 with modules in asp.net razor pages

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, razor-pages

At the end of the nightmarish razor code my employer wants us to write, I need to load a script block to run Vue3 on top of the rendered html.

Unfortunately, what I need to be able to do is way beyond the simple things they were doing with vue. I have already created various components that I want to use, and I was loading them in my standalone vueJs project in main.js.

However this doesn't work in their simplistic format, it fails on "import" which can't be done outside of a module:

```
@section Scripts{
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  <script>
    import { createApp } from "vue";
    import PopupManager from "/vue3/src/services/PopupManager.js";
    //import Validator from "/src/services/Validator.js";
    import dayjs from "dayjs";
    import App from "./App.vue";
    import Datepicker from '/vue3/node_modules/vuepic/vue-datepicker';
    import '/vue3/node_modules/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css'
    import PopUp from "/vue3/src/controls/PopUp.vue";
    const app = Vue.createApp({
      data(){ 
        return { 
            model: @Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model))
        };
      },
    })

    app.provide("dayjs", dayjs);
    app.config.globalProperties.$dayJs = dayjs;
    app.provide("PopUpManager", PopupManager);
    app.config.globalProperties.$popUpManager = PopupManager;
    app.provide("Validator", Validator);
    app.config.globalProperties.$validator = Validator;
    app.component("DatePicker", Datepicker);
    app.component("PopUp", PopUp);
    app.mount('#vueAppRoot');
  </script>
}
```

So how do I create modules out my components that I can load?

I have seen stack overflow answers that discuss "vue-template-compiler" in this context but they are extremely opaque about:

- How you setup the project.
- How you use it in the razor pages.

It doesn't help that the "vue-template-compiler" project has such terrible documentation itself.

I also don't like the idea of just pointing to a cdn and not compiling the modules or unit testing them. I would like for them to be built like they would for a real vueJs app.

I have a partial answer. You have to load your components as javascript in the script section:

```
@section Scripts {
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.40"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/vue/icons/IconHelp.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/vue/icons/IconState.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const { createApp, ref, computed } = Vue;
    let vueApp = createApp({
      data() { return {
        model: @Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model)),
        data: {
          acceptedAddress: false,
        },
      },
      methods: {
        showPopup() {
            this.$popUpManager.showPopup("AddressPopup", null);
        },
      }
    });
    vueApp.component("IconHelp", IconHelp);
    vueApp.component("IconState", IconState);

    vueApp.mount('#vueAppRoot');
    console.log(typeof IconHelp);
  </script>
}
```

This also means that you have to write the components like this:

```
const IconState = {
  template:
    `<span class="icon iconState">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 15192 15190">
        <path :class="{ medGray: !complete, iconColor: complete }" d="M7596 0c4195,0 7596,3400 7596,7595 0,4195 -3401,7595 -7596,7595 -4195,0 -7596,-3400 -7596,-7595 0,-4195 3401,-7595 7596,-7595z"/>
        <template v-if="!complete">
          <path class="lightGray" d="M7596 748c3782,0 6848,3066 6848,6847 0,3782 -3066,6847 -6848,6847 -3782,0 -6848,-3065 -6848,-6847 0,-3781 3066,-6847 6848,-6847z"/>
        </template>
        <template v-else>
          <path class="white" d="M12087 6142c422,-423 422,-1113 0,-1536 -423,-422 -1113,-422 -1536,0l-4196 4196 -1714 -1714c-422,-423 -1113,-423 -1535,0 -423,423 -423,1113 0,1536l2481 2481c423,423 1113,423 1536,0l4964 -4963z"/>
        </template>
      </svg>
    </span>`,
  name: "IconState",
  props: {
    complete: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
};
```

And of course any stylesheet has to be global, loaded separately.

On top of this ASP.Net javaScript debugging seems totally messed up on the ill-conceived project I'm working on.

I'm getting an error about:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (and a line number in the generated razor page)
```

but clicking on it doesn't show any code. Lovely. Any suggestions on how to make javaScript debugging actually work would be very helpful.

Comment: I think it may be possible to wrap the entire thing in its own object, so that any constants such defineComponent or ref don't interact with anything else on the page.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to build more complex components, the syntax below works. You can use the simpler format for components that don't use ref or reactive. My more complex components needed to use ref, but I could not load it in our environment at the window level.

There is a lot that is still dang horrible about this, if you make a single syntax error in any of the .js file loaded in @section scripts, the resulting bundle made by ASP.net will crash the app and the Chrome debugger will not let you inspect the code to find out where you made your mistake.

Thankfully code errors that aren't syntax problems still work with the debugger.

```
const { defineComponent } = Vue;

const MyComp = defineComponent({
  template: `template html here`,
  name: "MyComp",
  setup() {
// I had to use ref inside this function because getting it at the
// window level breaks other code in the application
    const { ref } = Vue;
    return {
      data: ref ({
        id: null,
    somethingElse: 0,
      })
    };
  },
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
 },
  methods: {
    someMethod(x) {
       //code here//
    },
  },
  //other complex things work too:
  mounted() {
    
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
  },
});
```